# Tableau calculation with attributes

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new with tableau and I try to calculate with different attributes from one dimension and one measure. 
[image]

I want to calculate the sum of the attributes RC,RD and RP and divide this by RI. I would be very thankfull if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create two calculated fields.

```
if [Rrid] = 'RC' or [Rrid] = 'RD' or [Rrid] = 'RP' then [Rrem] end
```

Then create the same for RI. Divide the first by the second

```
sum(calc1) / sum(calc2)
```

Comment: It's a bit shorter and easier to understand if you do it like that: `if [Rrid] = 'RC' or [Rrid] = 'RD' or [Rrid] = 'RP' then [Rrem] end`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is now, that RI doesn't have any data for 2010,2011, and 2012. So Tableau can't calculate further. I tried to create a cero for all null values with:
if [Rrid] = 'RI' then LOOKUP(SUM([Rrem]),0) END 
However this gives me the following error:
cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate comparisons or results in 'if' expressions
Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Try IFNULL([Rrem],0) for the RI calc.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I tried your function as you can see on the Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6J2f_blg_nga2ppVGIwa2lXdXM/view?usp=sharing